# CheckBox, action event

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I need to add a `Check box`, and when the user `checks` on it (as in changes the value `check/uncheck`) to print a `console.log` statement. So far i was able to display the check box, but unable to access its check event.

```
{
    xtype: 'checkboxgroup',
    columns: 1,

    listeners: {
        change: function (this, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
            console.log('change');
            console.log(newValue);
        }
    },
    items: [{
        boxLabel: 'Cars',
        name: 'chk1',
        inputValue: '1'
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As for any other field, the [change](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Field-event-change) event should work.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mbbjz/2/

Comment: how to do i get the value of the checkbox clicked. I got this ` 

change: function(this,newValue, oldValue, eOpts){` and i get an error `missing formal parameter`. I think i miss something.

Comment: @RazairoAluguera: can you update your code in the question please?

Comment: `field.fieldLabel` gives the fieldLabel, and not the CheckBox name `boxLabel` in my case. I changed `field.boxLabel` but it says `undefined`

Comment: Thank you, now i get the `Index` `1 and 2`. Is there a possibility to get the `boxLabel` name instead ?